# Why are my Java Appium tests working locally, but flakey when run against Browserstack?

Tags: java, cucumber, appium, cucumber-java, browserstack

I've put together some test suites written in Java using the Cucumber framework and they work fine against Appium when run locally. However, when i run the tests on Browserstack, the tests randomly fail. Sometimes, when the tests are run on Browserstack, the app opens on the home screen, instead of the setup screen that appears before this when running the app the first time. And other times, the tests fail on a text input screen saying that the element couldn't be found, despite the fact that the debug screenshots display the correct screen.

Has anyone else encountered this?

I've tried changing the desired capabilities to force the app to open at the right screen, but this brings back errors saying that the App Package or App Activity can't be found even though it's correct.

```
capabilities.setCapability("device", "Samsung Galaxy S9");
capabilities.setCapability("os_version", "8.0");
capabilities.setCapability("name", "Your.MD Regression test");
capabilities.setCapability("app", browserStackAppReference);
capabilities.setCapability("automationName", "Appium");
capabilities.setCapability("browserstack.appium_version", "1.12.1");
capabilities.setCapability("browserstack.debug", true);
capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "md.your.qa");
capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "md.your.onboarding.carousel.OnboardingCarouselActivity");
capabilities.setCapability("appWaitActivity", "md.your.onboarding.carousel.OnboardingCarouselActivity");
appiumUrl="https://"+userName+":"+accessKey+"@hub-cloud.browserstack.com/wd/hub";
```

I expect the tests to all pass as they do locally.

Answer (score 0):

To start an application at a particular Activity, you can make use of the Start Activity Command in Appium: http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/device/activity/start-activity/
Also, can you please share the error stack trace that you are encountering when the element is not visible.

Comment: This is the error message:

```Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create a new remote session. Please check the server log for more details. Original error: Error occurred while starting App. App Package or App Activity used to start the app doesn't exist or cannot be launched! Make sure the App Package is correct and the App Activity is a launchable activity. (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)```